# Access to PC-webserver from outside the network

Tags: networking, router, webserver

I can access the website from my local network but from outside every time I tried by entreating the public IP of my network I got access to my router page instead of my web-server "the website"

- The external Port is: 8080
- Internal Port is: 80
- My server have static IP and I point the port from the router to my server IP
- My network with static IP too
- I have checked the port with port checker and it's OPEN on my public IP

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Does the same thing happen from both inside the network and from outside?

Comment: I checked from outside "This page isn't working, xx.xx.xx.xx took too long to respond" HTTP error 504

Comment: Is your web server properly configured to accept connections from IP addresses outside your network? Look in its access logs to see if the connection is getting to the server.

Comment: Yes I checked that twice "Access from all" I checked the log, all IP from inside the network, Should I map the IP inside host file to something to make that work? because for now it's only like this "127.0.0.1 localhost" only that!

Comment: It works now :) There is two services on the same port, by changing it everything work great, thanks everyone